# How to programmatically add instances in Python?

Tags: python, class, metaprogramming

I want to compile `instance's attributes`  importing data from external (.csv) file programmatically. So far I can do it manually one instance at time. Using this workflow:

```
class RS: #the calss has the importer method and many attributes
   ... 
#workflow starts here
a=RS() #I create the instance
a.importer('pathofthefile') #the importer method fills the attributes of the instance with the exeternal file
#ends here and restart...
b=RS()
b.importer('path...
```

I would like to create instances programmatically and fill them with `importer` of the `class`.How can I iterate this process over large number of files? e.g. using `listdir`for import all the files from a folder?
I though something like this for creating the instances:

```
for i in 'abcd':
    eval('%s=RS()' %(i))
```

But of course seems not working..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't read them into variables with different names -- how would you use the variables?

Instead, read them into a *data structure* with a single name.

Let's put the actual process of making an instance and importing into a function:

```
def read_instance(filename):
    instance = RS()
    instance.importer(filename)
    return instance
```

Then you can for instance make a list:

```
instances = [read_instance(filename) for filename in 'abcd']

print len(instances)  # Prints 4
print instance[0]  # Prints the first
print instance[1]  # Prints the second, etc
```

Or a dictionary:

```
instances = {filename: read_instance(filename) for filename in 'abcd'}

print instances['c']  # Prints the instance corresponding to filename 'c'
```

Comment: +1 I believe this is the best answer (and also solves the embarrassing duplicate-like issue among me and Alexander) :)

Comment: Sure. My answer was meant only to show how to use metaprogramming. Ofc, the correct solution is the above.

Comment: Yes very clever this solves two problems, I was thinking to ask another question to understand how retrieve a list of all the instances created but now I don't need it any more...

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `eval` deals only with expressions. To use statements u should use `exec`:

```
>>>exec 'print 1'
1
```

But this is not the best way to to it. You cat use `globals` to access and change your global variables:

```
>>>globals()['b'] = 1
>>>b
1
```

So the solution might look like this:

```
for var_name in 'abcd':
    globals()[var_name] = RS()
    globals()[var_name].importer('...
```

Answer (score 2):

here is how I would like to do it, using [globals()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) built-in:

```
for i in 'abcd':
   globals()[i] = RS()
   globals()[i].importer('pathofthefile')
```

to add something different to Alexander's answer :) I would like to highlight that this method is not applicable to [locals()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals), that should be used only to read the variables and not to set them.

Comment: ops. almost a duplicate of Alexander's one.

Comment: That happens). I also unintentionally duplicated your post, sorry for that.